# Can't get Skype to shut up when signing off

Tags: 12.04, skype

I use Ubuntu 12.04 and I don't want Skype to play a sound file each time I sign on, off, receive a text message, etc. So I made fitting settings in the options menu, and it works for everything except for "Skype Logout". Reinstalling didn't work. Here are the things that I tried to do to shut it up: I unticked the box that says "play sound file". At first it worked, but after I had restarted it played the sound file again. Then I made an mp3 which had no sound in it and told skype to play that file. Same thing. First it worked but as soon as I restarted, it made the sound again. 3rd thing I tried: I unticked the box that says "Enable Event". Same results. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You could always delete the sound file. I couldn't get Skype to stop playing the sound either so that what I ended up doing. The sound files are located under `/usr/share/skype/sounds/`